# Filename_test is not executed by pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am learning pytest and tried creating a py file ending with _test also method name ending with _test. But when i run pytest command my test methods is not getting collected.

And when i mrename the method name starting with test_ then pytest is able to collect the test.

Can anyone please help me to understand what could be the issue here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it uses pictures to convey code. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2081835)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pytest by default uses `test_*`. If you want `*_test` then you have write the rule in `pytest.ini` file

Comment: Hi Anand, where i can find pytest.ini file? @anandbgautam

Comment: Also how i can change the default config in pytest.ini file?

Comment: @QASateesh  you have to create the pytest.ini file in your project.
Here is a [link](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/configuration-file-of-pytest-pytest.ini.html) which you can refer to. At the bottom of the page is about the test file nomenclature